# Inconsistent file contents on uploading through Dropbox API

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api, filereader

I am using the [Dropbox Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put) to upload and download files via a chrome extension. When I upload text files such as with extensions .txt, .js, .json or .c the files get uploaded successfully but when I upload files with extensions .pdf, .jpg etc (media files) then the contents are disfigured or absent, though the file size is non-zero, sometimes even larger than the original file. This clearly means that the data that is read is being written as well but I guess there is some problem with the way I am reading or writing the data. The code is posted below for reference.

```
$(document).on("click", "#id_submit",uploadProcess);

function uploadProcess()
{
    var file = $("#upload_file")[0].files[0];
    console.log(file);

    if (!file){
        alert ("No file selected to upload.");
        return false;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    //reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        uploadFile(file.name, evt.target.result, file.size, file.type);
        //console.log(evt.target.result);
        var control = $("#upload_file");
        control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ));
    }
}


//function to upload file to folder
function uploadFile(filepath,data,contentLength,contentType){
    var url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/"+filepath;
    var headers = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken(),
        contentLength: contentLength
    }
    var args = {
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        crossDomain: true,
        crossOrigin: true,
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: contentType,
        data : data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR)
        {
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    };
    $.ajax(args);
}
```

Comment: You are always putting contentType as 'text/plain', which works fine for text files you mentioned, but doesn´t for the others, replace it with your contentType variable you are sending to the function

Comment: @juvian Sorry I posted the old code here, I had already corrected that, now I am passing the content type after reading the `file.type`. Still the problem persists.

Comment: Try using readAsArrayBuffer instead. If it still does not work, try adding an Accept header of text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1  and putting content type as text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: @juvian that doesn't works either. Revised code posted here. http://jsfiddle.net/x4Lrj67x/

Comment: weird, try sending a email to dropbox support

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass a file in your ajax request(depending on browser support). Just pass the files in your args object, also you need to set processDate and contentType to false to prevent $.ajax from manipulating the file object

```
var args = {
    ...
    contentType: false,
    data : file,
    processData: false,
    ...
};
```

Comment: I know we can pass a file in ajax request but that is not consistent with the dropbox api specifications.

Comment: @bawejakunal I don't see any inconsistency. Did you try it?